# Tree view in laravel

Tags: laravel, tree

I have two tables

1. letters table :(id , letter_Id, name , letter_parent , letter_type, created_date .....).

There is self relation inside table between letterid and letterparent.

2)letter_event :( id , letter_id , name,  created_date .....).

There are one to many relation between letters and letter_event.

So,I want to display letter and letter_event based on date.

For example:

[image: Example]

Comment: you can use laravel adjacency list, https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list